# Remove trailing slash from previous_posts_link()

Tags: urls

I'm trying to remove trailing slash from a link which I get from `previous_posts_link()` function. Here is my code:

```
<?php rtrim(previous_posts_link( __( 'text', 'name' ) ), '/'); ?>
```

Unfortunetly it doesn't work and I still get the slash at the end of url.

Comment: Why do you want to remove that trailing slash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two problems here:

1. `previous_posts_link()` *echoes* the link, rather than returning it.
2. `previous_posts_link()` returns the full HTML of the link, including `<a href="">` etc.

The problem with #1 is that for you to be able pass the result of a function to another function (such as `rtrim()`) as an argument, that function needs to `return` a value, not print it to the screen using `echo` or similar. The function that *returns* the value of `previous_posts_link()` is [`get_previous_posts_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_previous_posts_link/).

However, this still won't solve your problem, because of #2. `get_previous_posts_link()` will return a value like this:

```
'<a href="https://example.com/2019/02/08/previous-post/">« Previous Post</a>'
```

As you can see, this does not end with a slash. The slash is in the middle of the string as part of the URL.

If you only want the URL, you need to use [`get_previous_posts_page_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_previous_posts_page_link/). *Then* you can remove the trailing slash:

```
<?php echo rtrim( get_previous_posts_page_link(), '/' ); ?>
```

Now, just to cover all my bases; if you want to get the full HTML link and remove the trailing slash from inside it, then you're going to need a couple more steps.

Firstly, you're going to need to use `get_previous_posts_link()`, which is the function that returns the full HTML, rather than echoing it. Then you're going to need to extract the URL from the HTML, remove the trailing slash, then put it back. That will look something like this:

```
// Get the HTML for the link.
$previous_posts_link = get_previous_posts_link( __( 'text', 'name' ) );

// Find the URL.
preg_match( '/href="([^"]*)"/', $previous_posts_link, $matches );

// Remove the trailing slash from the original URL.
$original_url = $matches[1];
$trimmed_url  = untrailingslashit( $original_url );

// Replace the original URL with the version without a slash.
$previous_posts_link = str_replace( $original_url, $trimmed_url, $previous_posts_link );

// Output it
echo $previous_posts_link;
```

I have no idea why you'd want or need to do that though.

PS: `untrailingslashit()` is a WordPress helper function that removes trailing forward and back slashes.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this line to your functions.php

```
add_filter('get_pagenum_link','untrailingslashit');
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add line to your functions.php

```
add_filter('paginate_links','untrailingslashit');
```